# Trying to test fastapi startup event breaks other tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fastapi

I have a FastAPI application (Python version 3.9.7, FastAPI version 0.82.0) and I'm trying to test the "startup" event in the main.py file:

```
@app.on_event("startup")
def startup_event():
    utils.remote_example_call()
```

My test for this in the test module looks like this:

```
def test_startup_event():
    with patch("app.utils.remote_example_call") as mock_remote_example_call:
        mock_remote_example_call.return_value = None
        with TestClient(app) as client:
            response = client.get("/health")
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert mock_remote_example_call.call_count == 1
```

When I run the application in a Docker container and then run this command in that container:

```
pytest /tests/unit/ --asyncio-mode=strict
```

I get this output:

```
_______________________________________________________________________________________ test_get_database ________________________________________________________________________________________

mocker = <pytest_mock.plugin.MockerFixture object at 0xffffad0fbf40>

>   ???
E   AssertionError: assert <botocore.client.DynamoDB object at 0xffffad29f910> == 'my_database'
E    +  where <botocore.client.DynamoDB object at 0xffffad29f910> = <function get_database at 0xffffaece1430>()
E    +    where <function get_database at 0xffffaece1430> = repository_helper.get_database

/opt/project/tests/unit/helpers/test_repository_helper.py:17: AssertionError
======================================================================================== warnings summary ========================================================================================
test_main.py::test_startup_event
  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py:542: DeprecationWarning: The loop argument is deprecated since Python 3.8, and scheduled for removal in Python 3.10.
    results = await tasks.gather(

helpers/test_example_call_helper.py::test_send_agent_message
  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_content.py:204: DeprecationWarning: Use 'content=<...>' to upload raw bytes/text content.
    warnings.warn(message, DeprecationWarning)

helpers/test_repository_helper.py::test_get_database
  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest_trio/plugin.py:62: TrioDeprecationWarning: trio.MultiError is deprecated since Trio 0.22.0; use BaseExceptionGroup (on Python 3.11 and later) or exceptiongroup.BaseExceptionGroup (earlier versions) instead (https://github.com/python-trio/trio/issues/2211)
    if issubclass(call.excinfo.type, trio.MultiError):

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
==================================================================================== short test summary info =====================================================================================
FAILED ../tests/unit/helpers/test_repository_helper.py::test_get_database - AssertionError: assert <botocore.client.DynamoDB object at 0xffffad29f910> == 'my_database'
============================================================================ 1 failed, 68 passed, 3 warnings in 0.94s ============================================================================
```

Which shows and error in a different test module altogether. If I comment out the `test_startup_event` the tests work.

How can I get things working correctly?

Comment: Are the impacted code areas using `remote_example_call` function as well? If yes, try limit the patch of `remote_example_call` to the module it's used in the startup.

Comment: The impacted code isn't using `remote_example_call`, at least not directly, it's part of the fastAPI startup event code. However, I think I have limited the patch to just the test functionality.

Comment: While I agree that it is weird that other tests break, I want to ask why you are doing this? Since you’re mocking `utils.remote_example_call` (which I assume you have other tests for) the only thing you are trying to test is that FastAPI actually runs the startup command on startup, i.e. testing that a library does what it says it does. I would consider this quite a bad practice.

Comment: The person who built the repository and project wants 100% test coverage, which is why I added a test for the startup event.